# Bleeding Edge for Selected Programs

Tags: ppa

I am running 10.04 and have Octave 3.2.3 installed. Recently, I decided to try my hand at development and hence wanted my Octave copy to stay on the Bleeding Edge.

Ordinarily, this could be done by using a PPA and adding it to sources (correct?) but Octave doesn't have a PPA. So, how do make sure that every time I begin writing a development code, my copy of Octave is the latest one.

My apologies if this question has already been asked.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean, sure! That'd be great

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`lucid-bleed`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/930148) PPA. It is a PPA that backports the latest stable versions of several applications to Lucid Lynx.

Add it like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucid-bleed/ppa
```

To install the latest version of *Octave* you just have to update your archives and install it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

If you already have Octave installed then just do an upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```